# CCTimer being leaked in cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1 using scheduled selectors

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

I'm now looking for memory leaks in my `cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1` game using the Leaks instrument.

So far so good, I've fixed several problems. But there is one object being leaked that I can't quite understand:

It is a `CCTimer` object. The line that leads to this leak is

```
// This method is called when you encounter a random battle.
-(void)transitionToBattle {
    [self unschedule:@selector(transitionToBattle)];

    // Displays a "loading" screen
    [self schedule:@selector(battleLoading)interval:0.5];

    // Enters actual battle scene
    [self schedule:@selector(enterBattle) interval:0.8];   // <--- Leak here
}
```

Not sure if relevant, but the `enterBattle` method is

```
-(void)enterBattle {
    [self unschedule:@selector(enterBattle)];

    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector]pushScene:[BattleScene scene]];
}
```

`battleLoading` merely displays a sprite over the screen:

```
-(void)battleLoading {
    [self unschedule:@selector(battleLoading)];

    // The scene itself is running a CCRotateBy action, so I'll stop it
    [self stopAllActions];

    // << Create CCSprite for "now loading" here >>

    // It is possible for the scene to be rotated, so let's fix that
    self.rotation = 0.0;

    // Make sure that the rotation fix is noticed
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector]drawScene];
}
```

---

I understand that cocos2d uses a `CCTimer` to control scheduled selectors. However, I don't have the faintest idea on how could it possibly be leaking a `CCTimer`.

The code where these methods are located is quite large, but I'm certain that the snippets above are the only parts referencing `enterBattle`.

I can notice the leak once you are already in the battle scene, so it doesn't happen when you exit it. The leak doesn't occur always, just often.

I can see that the details above are not quite accurate, making it hard to pinpoint the problem. So instead I'd like to know if there is a reasonable way to debug a leaked `CCTimer` because of a schedule. What could possibly cause this?

---

And it seems to happen only with this specific schedule. I have lots of other ones and none seem to leak like this.

Comment: it could simply be a false positive

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: I didn't know that could happen! Is there a way to verify?

Comment: one sure way is to check live objects, or override cctimer init and dealloc and log the number of active timers respectively to verify if the supposedly leaked timer eventually does dealloc

Comment: yep ... false positives, non-detection, and many other inaccuracies are your lot with instruments. In my class templates, i have de-facto the appropriate 'live instance' count mechanisms in init and dealloc. Very useful to track abandoned memory, under/over releasing. And dont give me that ARC bromide Stefen :)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: It seems like it was `[[CCDirector sharedDirector]drawScene];` what caused the leak (for some reason I don't know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the culprit was this:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]drawScene];
```

In my `battleLoading` method.

I don't really know why. I just removed it and so far I haven't seen the leak again.

Taking a look at this method for `CCDirectorIOS`, it seems to do something related to the scheduler. Maybe it isn't quite friendly with schedules, specially when you're changing scenes or something.